# Access to Administrator account from unknown computer names

Tags: windows, networking, active-directory, security

For a few weeks all our DCs has received thousands of failed logins for "Administrator".
Event viewer logs below messages, NOTE we have no computers or servers on the network with the names, they seem very generic.
We have tried to trace the connections but ProcessMonitor, Antimalware, internal ports etc shows nothing. Anyone with ideas how to trace this further?

EventID: 4776
Type: NETWORK

````
Logon Account:  Administrator
Source Workstation: Windows2016
Error Code: 0xc000006a
The computer attempted to validate the credentials for an account.

Authentication Package: MICROSOFT_AUTHENTICATION_PACKAGE_V1_0
Logon Account:  Administrator
Source Workstation: FreeRDP
Error Code: 0xc000006a
The computer attempted to validate the credentials for an account.

Authentication Package: MICROSOFT_AUTHENTICATION_PACKAGE_V1_0
Logon Account:  Administrator
Source Workstation: Windows2012
Error Code: 0xc000006a
The computer attempted to validate the credentials for an account.

Authentication Package: MICROSOFT_AUTHENTICATION_PACKAGE_V1_0
Logon Account:  Administrator
Source Workstation: Windows10
Error Code: 0xc000006a
The computer attempted to validate the credentials for an account.```
````

Comment: What AD-integrated service do you have open to the internet?  OWA?  Remote Desktop?

Comment: None as far as I know, that's why we need to investigate where it is coming from

Comment: I second Mr. Semicolon: it looks like some Internet-exposed service that is being brute forced. Maybe RDP-related. If you have Windows logs from your servers, try to look for failed logon attempts (4625) - on the server itself that is being brute forced, there should be such event ideally.

Answer (score 1):

You can run Wireshark on the server, and then look for Kerberos traffic. This will be a time consuming approach if you have lots of servers in the Domain.

Comment: I have a few hundred servers, and a few thousand users so the Wireshark log "explodes" if I can't be more specific

Comment: In the Filter, exclude your trusted Networks, say you have all Production servers in 10.0.0.0/16 Network, remove them from capture. Or do it the other way, start with smaller subnets, and then rule them out one by one. It is not going to be something simple, it will take time and effort to track it down via Wireshark. You will need to take time stamp Eventlog, and then look at the relevant time frame in Wireshark. If you have budget, you can also try 3rd Party tools like ManageEngine have ADAudit Plus, which I haven't tried myself for this Event ID.